# Where can I find the source code for the Ubuntu Kernel?

Tags: kernel

I'd like to build my own copy of the Ubuntu kernel. Where can I get the source code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For building kernels, it is strongly suggested that you use git to get
the latest source code from the Ubuntu kernel git repositories.

These repositories contain all updates to Ubuntu kernels, including ones
which are proposed for release but not released yet. By fetching from
the repos, you will be guaranteed to have the latest code.

If you want to fetch the source for a specific release, you may check
out the tag associated with that release. Tags are similar to this
example: "Ubuntu-2.6.32-17.26". The final number is an upload number
which is sequentially increased, and the rest is the version number.

You can see a list of the Ubuntu kernel repositories here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git

This page also lists a number of repositories for individual developers.
The official Ubuntu kernel repositories begin with "ubuntu/ubuntu-"

If you are looking to just get the sources to the kernel that you are
currently running you can:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: 6 years old, and the first *useful* answer for http/ftp I have found amongst dozens.

Comment: There are issues with `apt-get source`, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/938955/119231) to download directly from launchpad.

Comment: No longer works on Ubuntu 20.04, only meta data is downloaded by now

Answer (score 4):

Best place is from the kernel team git repositories, see:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide

Answer (score 3):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

follow this steps, before `apt-get source` you should run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: No longer works

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can find the Linux Kernel maintenance here: [LaunchPad: Linux Kernel](https://launchpad.net/linux)

However, while the kernel for Ubuntu may be referred to as the Ubuntu Kernel - it's actually the Linux Kernel modified by the [Ubuntu Kernel Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-team). You can find more information about the [Ubuntu Kernel Members](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam) and how to get the [Ubuntu Kernel using Git](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide) on the [Ubuntu Wiki: Kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel)

Comment: You do have a good point about finding information on the kernel team's wiki pages.

Answer (score 2):

**Download from the Git Repo:**

```
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/$RELEASE_NAME
```

On Jammy Jellyfish (22.04), for example:

```
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy
```

Comment: That's a good update. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unmodified Linux Kernel at [kernel.org](http://kernel.org).

Comment: These of course are not the Ubuntu kernels, but the kernel source on which the Ubuntu kernels are based.