# How can I download the source code for linux-image-3.2.0-*-generic?

Tags: kernel, source-code

The directions at [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode) `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` and [askubuntu question Where can I find the source code for the Ubuntu Kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2964/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-the-ubuntu-kernel) don't work…

```
sudouser@64bitws:~# uname -r
3.2.0-24-generic
```

and

```
sudouser@64bitws:~# apt-get source linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic'
E: Unable to find a source package for linux
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade first`? Also, does searching for "complete generic linux kernel" in Synaptic show a "linux" package?

Comment: @izx Yes and no

Comment: Try the following command: apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use Ubuntu Software Center…

[image]

…but it's very slow  *⋯about 1KiB/s*