# Where can I find the source code to the kernel shipped in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, kernel, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the source code for the Ubuntu Kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2964/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-the-ubuntu-kernel)

I downloaded 12.04 LTS desktop and compiled kernel.
Loaded the new kernel but i did not get wireless.

I have questions.
Where do I find the exact kernel source code that of my operating system and how to compile.