# How do I recompile the kernel?

Tags: kernel, make

I read from wireless developers that I have to run `make menuconfig` command to change some configuration of the wireless driver (enable/disable something). After changing, do I have to recompile the kernel to give effect to changes? If I have to, how to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to get the kernel sources. Please have a look at [the answer to »Getting the kernel source in Ubuntu«](https://askubuntu.com/a/159842/236). It shows you where to get the sources. If you used the command `apt-get source linux-source`, you'll a tar.gz-file. You can double-click on it to unpack or use the command line:

```
tar xfz linux.tar.gz
```

You might also need several other packages. This command installs all needed:

```
sudo apt-get install git kernel-package fakeroot build-essential ncurses-dev
```

Now you should change into the directory where your kernel sources reside. If you downloaded it with `git` they might be in the subdirectory `linux`. Otherwise they are copied to `/usr/src`.

In the next step you should copy your existing kernel config file to the source tree:

```
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
```

And now you can execute

```
make menuconfig
```

and enter your changes. Please see also the site [GitKernelBuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) in the Ubuntu wiki for more advice.
After you saved your changes you can compile your new kernel:

```
CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
```

and if you enter `ls ..` you'll see some `.deb` files. You can install them and use your new kernel.

Comment: I followed "apt-get source linux-source..." and dowloaded a "linux...tar.gz". Now do I have to extract it?

Comment: Yes, I added some lines in my answer.

Comment: please help me until I finish it. Now, I am at extracted folder, run command "cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config" and "make menuconfig". I made my changes and then recompile kernel. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, if you type `make menuconfig` there should appear a menu on the command. line

Answer (score 1):

You can look [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_ubuntu_p2) for more instructions for a Debian specific way.

> To build the kernel, execute these two commands:
>
> ```
> make-kpkg clean
> fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
> ```
>
> After `--append-to-version=` you can write any string that helps you
>   identify the kernel, but it must begin with a minus (-) and must not
>   contain whitespace.

[This site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html) has more generic instructions, which look a lot more familiar:

> Start compiling to create a compressed kernel image, enter:
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> Start compiling to kernel modules:
>
> ```
> make modules
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Recompiling current 5.4.0 kernel on 20.04**

Preparation

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential bison flex gcc-9 g++-9 libncurses libncurses-dev libssl-dev
```

The next will download current kernel sources

```
$ sudo apt install linux-source
```

Go to the directory with kernel sources archive and extract it

```
$ cd /usr/src/linux-source-5.4.0/   
$ sudo tar xvfj linux-source-5.4.0.tar.bz2   
$ cd linux-source-5.4.0
```

Configure kernel

```
$ sudo make menuconfig
```

Change it if you like, save and exit
Compile it using your number of threads after a "-j" option

```
$ sudo make -j2 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-cust
```

Install it

```
$ sudo apt install ../linux-*cust*.deb
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/@ayrn/how-to-custom-build-xanmod-kernel-on-ubuntu-18-04-2d628db52317) could help