# From where I download kerenl source code for version 3.8.0-29-generic

Tags: kernel

```
heena@heena:~$ uname -r
3.8.0-29-generic
```

Also

```
heena@heena:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I want to download source code for this version. From where I can get the source code for this? [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) is not having this version listed

Comment: any reason for wanting that specific ancient kernel?

Comment: I assume [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/159842/230683) answer could help you.

Comment: actually this the kernel I am having in my system. and I want to add a system call.

Comment: You should consider bump it up to the *latest* minor version, at the moment 3.8.0-35, cause of security.