# Fetching the kernel source code using git

Tags: 12.04, kernel, source-code

I am having Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my PC.

```
heena@heena:~$ uname -r
3.8.0-29-generic
```

Also

```
heena@heena:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Following suggestions from [How do I get the kernel source code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code) I am issuing the following command to get the source code of the *kernel*:

```
git clone git //kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
```

But my doubt is how does the above command know I have to download the kernel version

> 3.8.0-29-generic

? The above command is not having such version? Is this command for downloading just kernel or the whole ubuntu? I am interested only in kernel. 
Also in which folder the source is being downloaded, that is also not clear to me.

**UPDATE**

To be precise my doubts will be cleared if someone can help me know:

Which version of kernel will be downloaded from the above command ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [Ans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46077/where-to-download-linux-kernel-source-code-of-a-specific-version)

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
cd linux 
git checkout v2.6.36.2
```

To later switch to another version, it's easy:

```
git checkout v3.5.2
```

To update your repository to include all of the latest tags and
commits:

```
git fetch
```

and for detailed steps Look at [KernelBuild](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild)

Comment: why is my version 3.8.0-29-generic not listed on kernel.org?

Comment: I dont think mere copy paste of someone else's answer is of any help in SE sites...