# Downloading specific version of ubuntu kernel

Tags: kernel

I need to download specific version of ubuntu kernel source code (ubuntu version 16.04.4 and kernel 4.15.25-47). could anyone help me to download the specified kernel source code?

Comment: you can see here https://www.kernel.org/ but I don't' know if source code is available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the kernel source code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code)

Comment: There was never `4.15.25-47` Ubuntu kernel version. Where did you get this number?

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks, one of my clients has given me this number. how can i sure that this number is wrong? what is meaning of digit no.3 (in my case 25) in number (it is minor? patch? or what?)

Comment: This doesn't mean anything. Ubuntu kernels look like `4.15.0-xx.yy`. There was no `4.15.0-25.47`, so it is unclear.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks, there is any list/archive for ubuntu kernel?

Comment: There is a git repo https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/xenial