# Getting server kernel source

Tags: kernel, source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the source code for the Ubuntu Kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2964/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-the-ubuntu-kernel)

I'm trying to get the kernel source for the version of the kernel running on the cluster that I  have taken over administering, as I need the kernel source to update some 3rd party modules (lustre).

`uname -a` reports

```
Linux buster-fe0 2.6.32-33-server #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 21:21:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However when I try getting the kernel sources I get :

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-2.6.32-33-server'
NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid.git
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux_2.6.32.orig.tar.gz'
Need to get 5,522kB of source archives.
Err http:archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main linux 2.6.32-41.90 (dsc)
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Err http:archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main linux 2.6.32-41.90 (diff)
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http:archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_2.6.32-41.90.dsc  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
Failed to fetch http:archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_2.6.32-41.90.diff.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.192 80]
E: Failed to fetch some archives.
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here or how to fix it ?