# How do I access the Ubuntu source code?

Tags: source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu)

How do I obtain the source code for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386 32-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the source code for Ubuntu.

You can browse to the online archive [archive.ubuntu.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com)

You can download it through apt `apt-get source 'packagename'`

If you want the kernel, I'd start at http://www.kernel.org/

The problem with wanting the 'source for Ubuntu' is that the distribution is basically made up of a bunch of different packages.  I'd probably narrow down to what packages you want to look at and go from there.