# How can I download Ubuntu's source code from Windows?

Tags: windows, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu)

I am still learning C and I want to get Ubuntu's source code. Can I somehow get it on Windows?

(I can't install Ubuntu on my laptop, I wanted to dual boot but I don't understand how to manage the partitions.)

Can I download the source code from the Internet and open it with MS Visual C++? Should I get it in a virtual environment and somehow move it to Windows?

Thanks for help!

Comment: @Flimm I can't do that on Windows.

Comment: Could someone with experience with MS Visual C++ answer whether that IDE is useful for this use-case?

Comment: @MatejKranjec can you be more specific with question. Do you want view the source code of Ubuntu in Windows or do you install Ubuntu in virtual environment?.

Comment: @upsla I want to view the source code of Ubuntu in Windows. I already have installed Ubuntu in a virtual enviroment and it works.