# Where is the banshee folder?

Tags: banshee, source-code, music-player, source

I'd like to take a look to the source code but I can't find the right folder.

No the folder in the home directory, the one where the source and configuration is stored, a cd banshee isn’t going to work, I obviously need the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing make sure you download the code. The source code does not get downloaded by default (to save space).

Run this in a terminal (we are first creating a folder to contain the source files):

```
mkdir ~/banshee-source-dir
cd ~/banshee-source-dir
apt-get source banshee
```

if everything went OK, there should be a folder `~/banshee-source-dir/banshee-<version>` inside which the source code is located.

Notice that you can also browse the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/GNOME/banshee).

Answer (score 0):

From [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep $package
```

where the word 'package' indicates the source code of the program you desire to download.

then type:

```
sudo apt-get source $package
```

In your case, to download **Banshee's source code**, type:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep banshee
sudo apt-get source banshee
```

Comment: `apt-get build-dep` is only needed if you want to build the package. Just a remark so the OP does not think this is required to just read the code.