# How can I know which is the source of an specific standard shared libraries?

Tags: shared-library

How can I get access to the source code of standard shared libraries?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the concrete library you're looking for.

As an example, let's take a look at `/usr/lib/liba52-0.7.4.so` (this was simply the first file in my `/usr/lib` directory).

First, let's find out what package the file belongs to:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/liba52-0.7.4.so
liba52-0.7.4: /usr/lib/liba52-0.7.4.so
```

So now we know that the package name is `liba52-0.7.4`. To download the source code, use

```
$ apt-get source liba52-0.7.4
```

Note: no need to use `sudo`. The latter command will create a directory `a52dec-0.7.4/` in the working directory. This contains the source code.

Comment: What if it returns two or more packages? and is there any directory inside the Ubuntu source code for these library-related packages? Thanks again

Comment: A single file (such as a shared library) should only belong to a single package, not more. I do not understand your second question. As I said, the `apt-get source` command will create a directory with the package's source code inside the working directory, that is, the directory you're currently in at the moment where you type in the command.

Comment: It is weird since running dpkg -S /usr/lib/libical.so.0 on my laptop returns two package names while running it on my desktop returns only one package name...any way... In second question, I am  asking whether I can find the packages for these libraries inside an Ubuntu installation disk containing the source code or not? If so, please let me know where... Thank u once again

Comment: Which two package names do you get? For the library you mentioned, the corresponding package is `libical0`. Concerning your second question, no, the source code of libraries is not contained inside the Ubuntu installation disk.

Comment: /usr/lib/libical.so.0 and /usr/lib/libical.so.0.48.0

Comment: Are they the same?

Comment: Those are file names. Both belong to the same, single package, namely `libical0`. In fact, `/usr/lib/libical.so.0` is simply a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/libical.so.0.48.0`. While a single file only belongs to a single package, a single package usually contains several files.