# Where can I see the source code of UnZip

Tags: source-code

So I am interested in how UnZip handles it's -l function and would like to see the source code for it.

Where could I get my hands on that source code?

Comment: [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the source used in the Ubuntu package, go to:

```
https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unzip
```

You can also use:

```
apt-get source unzip
```

You may need to enable source repositories in your software preferences for the second option.

Answer (score 3):

General rule:

1. Head to http://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. Search for the package you want. In this case, you'll get to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unzip) page.
3. Look to the right. There is a "download source package" option. You want the tarball file.