# Ubuntu core snappy for rpi2 - source code

Tags: ubuntu-core, source-code, raspberrypi

I would like to work on ubuntu core snappy for raspberry Pi 2.
I got a the image - ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-raspi2.
How do I get the corresponding source code?

Thanks.
Said

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ubuntu Core is directly build from the Ubuntu distribution, just with a different set of packages.

So, what happens during builds is basically a traditional live creation, and removal of the debs and apt metadata in `/var/lib`.

To get this Ubuntu source code, you can simply refer to [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu) for instance!

Comment: But how do I build the same Ubuntu Core image as I can download for e.g. raspberry pi 3 myself?

Comment: I agree with @BjarkeFreund-Hansen The question isn't "Where can I find Ubuntu source code so I can change it into `Snappy Ubuntu Core` source code?". The question is where is Snappy Ubuntu Core source code that can be compiled in one step?