# Disable Ubuntu Core Autoupdate

Tags: package-management, updates, ubuntu-core

Ubuntu Core automatically updates installed snaps, for example 'core' snap, and to return to previous version I need to run the command

```
snap revert
```

But I want to control this myself and update manually only.

How to disable autoupdate of concrete snaps or disable this feature systemwide?

P.S. I have read [the documentation here on developer.ubuntu.com](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/autoupdate/) , but my system distribution of Ubuntu Core 16 on Raspberry Pi does not have a `snappy` command. How do I disable autoupdate without the `snappy` command?

Comment: Hmm, that page you link says that this autoupdate can potentially reboot my system.  I definitely don't want that.

Comment: Do you know how to disable autoupdate completely ?

Comment: No, I would like someone to answer your question.  I installed the snappy command from the link you provided, but it seemed to be some video app.  So I'm confused.

Comment: The link needs fixing

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable autoupdate. You can, however, [control the update schedule](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-schedule-via-core-config/434):

```
snap set core refresh.schedule=<spec>
```

I can't find an easily-accessible description of the `spec` (I'll update this answer if I do), but here are some examples:

- `9:00-15:00` (every day between 9am and 3pm)
- `9:00-15:00/21:00-22:00` (every day between 9am,5pm and 9pm,10pm)
- `thu@9:00-15:00` (only Thursday between 9am and 3pm)
- `fri@9:00-11:00/mon@13:00-15:00` (only Friday between 9am and 3pm and Monday between 1pm and 3pm)
- `fri@9:00-11:00/13:00-15:00`  (only Friday between 9am and 3pm and every day between 1pm and 3pm)