# How to disbale Auto update from Ubuntu-core?

Tags: ubuntu-core

How to disable Ubuntu-core 16 auto update?

I want update Ubuntu-core manually by command

How to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent automatic reboot after Ubuntu Core update on 16.xx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883460/prevent-automatic-reboot-after-ubuntu-core-update-on-16-xx)