# Sudo command and its source

Tags: sudo, source-code

The `sudo` command is at `/usr/bin/sudo` on my Xubuntu 16.04

I'm interested to know if anyone can advise which program I could use to open this `sudo` file and see what the `sudo` command is made up of?

I tried using a regular text editor but the file isn't correctly encoded so I can't see anything useful.

Comment: I think what you want is [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu). You can't read binary files (stuff in /usr/bin and so on)

Comment: Yeah something like that. I mean, I  was looking just for *sudo* source code but this is even wider spectrum. Thanks

Comment: actually, I think you will find what you want more easily [on the sudo website](https://www.sudo.ws/) - I edited the wiki answer to include this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo` is a command and it is an executable program.

You can find out more about how to use it using these commands in the terminal (in order of least -> most detailed):

```
sudo --help   
man sudo
info sudo
```

To understand more about how it works, you can [visit the sudo website](https://www.sudo.ws/) where you can [browse the source code](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo). You can also download the source code:

First edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

you will see these lines near the beginning:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

You have to uncomment the `deb-src` line (remove the #) so it says:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

Save the file and exit. Now run `sudo apt update` and then, to dowload the source code package *to the current working directory*

```
apt source sudo
```

**Super short summary**: sudo is short for 'superuser do' meaning 'execute the following command as the superuser'. Thus, it grants the humble user root privileges for one command and any commands triggered by that command.