# where do I get an Ubuntu 18.04 tarball? not iso

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I have to download a tarball to install Ubuntu into a Docker environment and can't find any tar.gz packages of Ubuntu 18.04 only .iso's. I cannot install a separate Docker provisioned Ubuntu container either. I need the actual tarball to install inside of a special directory of a development environment.
Where can I find what I need?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. What are you expecting the traball should contain?

Comment: the full os. everytime I go to the official Ubuntu site to download a desktop I get links for .iso package and I am not interested in installing it on a disk first - a straight tgz package is fine for this situation. Does the server install provide a tar.gz download?

Comment: You must make such a tarball yourself. Ubuntu is distributed using debs and snaps, not tarballs. Perhaps chrooting will accomplish what you need?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes this answers my question