# Where can I find the desktop environment source code like GNOME or KDE?

Tags: customization

I'm trying to understand how Linux's desktop environments made and how they work but I can't know where exactly they're installed and can't find any answers on google search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu). GNOME and KDE are compromised of dozens of packages

Comment: https://download.gnome.org/sources/

Comment: Just as you `apt install` to install binary packages, use the `apt` command to grab the source instead (or as well).  The packages themselves control where they are placed on the file-system when expanded (look inside the packages). This is a Ubuntu (and *flavor*) support site though, not generic GNU/Linux (SE *Unix & Linux* is that).