# Getting the source code for ubuntu

Tags: kernel

I did the following before updating the kernel:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Then I got this folder after unzipping:

```
linux-meta-4.15.0.60.62
```

But inside is just this:

```
debian/
```

and

```
update-version
```

But I don't see anything folders like `arch/` or`block`

Did I do something wrong? I already updated the kernel and I have a 4cpu pc so it took many hours to do this. How can I get the kernel from what I already downloaded? Also I took reference to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2964/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-the-ubuntu-kernel) and this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide) of instructions. I cloned bionic but need the version 4.15.0.60.62. So I then checked this out into a branch called temp. How do I get the files at this location? I tried to clone temp but it doesn't work.

Comment: You downloaded metapackage - those just serve as lists of bunch other packages to install, that's where source code actually is. Find out that package's dependencies and download those

Comment: The rules and what makes up the meta package can be found in the debian/ directory

Comment: It seems that you can't get kernel source code this way anymore. But you can get the source from git.

Comment: The `sudo apt install linux-source`  command is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current linux source code by

```
apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```